# SQL get common values in a database

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm using Sqlsrv and I need to find common values within the same table using PHP. There are two main columns, user_id and bssid.

Using a selected $user_id, I need to find all common "bssid" values and return a set of users which contain these values (this is if another user_id has one or more bssid the same).

This is my query string so far. My logic doesn't work.

```
    $sql = "SELECT A.* FROM AccessPoints A INNER JOIN (SELECT bssid, user_id
        FROM AccessPoints WHERE user_id='$userID'
        GROUP BY bssid, user_id
        HAVING COUNT(*) >= 1) B
        ON A.bssid = B.bssidB.user_id = A.user_id";
```

The database schema is as such:

[image: Image of database]

A sample of the dataset can be seen as such, and contains the data from two users:

[image: Image of database data entries]

I simply want to query a user_id and return all other user_ids which have similar bssids

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data and desire output. Also please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
     And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You mean select distinct user_id group by bassid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want all the user_id including the the one you are searching on then:

```
SELECT user_id 
FROM AccessPoints
WHERE bssid IN(SELECT bssid
               FROM AccessPoints) 
               WHERE user_id = '$userID')
```

If you want to exclude the one you are searching from the output then:

```
SELECT user_id 
FROM AccessPoints
WHERE bssid IN(SELECT bssid
               FROM AccessPoints) 
               WHERE user_id = '$userID')
  AND user_id != '$userID'
```

Comment: Excellent! Works really well and simple to understand. Thanks a bunch.